# Object linking order trouble

Tags: c, gcc

I am facing linking problem. I'll illustrate it:

a.c:

```
extern void b(void);
int main() {
    a();
    return 0;
}

void a() {
    b();
}
```

b.S:

```
.extern a
b:
    jmp a
```

No matter if I'll link

```
gcc a.o b.o -o c
```

or

```
gcc b.o a.o -o c
```

I'll get unresolved symbols. How do I link these files? I can't merge them. Example may be nonsensical, but that illustrates point, what do i try to archive.

Comment: A few questions: (a) what asm is that targeting?  none of yasm, nasm, nor gas like it.  (b) you need to forward declare `void a()` in `a.c` or it won't compile.  (c) changing `b()` to a C function and trying your link command works just fine.  To my knowledge, the only time you get the kind of ordering dependencies you're talking about for linking is in the behavior of the linker for static libraries.  Can you update the question to give a working example of the issue?

Comment: It IS gnu as.
I am writing operating system which grown large, and i thought about making an example like this.

Comment: sry, my issue w/gas was that my initial investigation was on mingw.  Moving to a proper linux let me assemble your example just fine.  Solution below.  TL;DR: the issue is that `b` was not global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial investigation:

**a.c**

```
extern void b(void);
void a(void);

int main() {
  a();
  return 0;
}

void a() {
  b();
}
```

**b.S**

```
.extern a
b:
  jmp a
```

**b.c**

```
void a(void);

void b(void)
{
  a();
}
```

**Output**

```
$ gcc -c a.c
$ gcc -c b.c -o b_gcc.o
$ as b.S -o b_as.o
$ gcc a.o b_gcc.o -o test_gcc
$ gcc a.o b_as.o -o test_as
a.o: In function `a':
a.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So what gives?  Why is it okay with GCC but not GAS?

```
$ objdump -t b_gcc.o > syms_gcc
$ objdump -t b_as.o > syms_as
$ diff syms_gcc syms_as
2c2
< b_gcc.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
---
> b_as.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
5d4
< 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*    0000000000000000 b.c
9,12c8
< 0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack  0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
< 0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame    0000000000000000 .eh_frame
< 0000000000000000 l    d  .comment 0000000000000000 .comment
< 0000000000000000 g     F .text    000000000000000b b
---
> 0000000000000000 l       .text    0000000000000000 b
```

Okay, so `gcc` makes `b` a global symbol.  Lets try `.global b` in `b.S`:

```
$ as b.S -o b_as2.o
$ gcc a.o b_as2.o
$
```

Success.  So `gcc`/`ld` *will* do multi-pass symbol resolution for anything that is not in a static library.  But it *only* looks for global symbols.  Here's the final `b.S`:

```
.extern a
.global b
b:
  jmp a
```

Comment: Also, didn't you use intelish syntax instead of AT&T?